# Is there a way to get conditional inputs in tkinter GUI dynamically, instead of getting them from the console?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, input, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a simple GUI for a pdf reading program I'd written using spyder IDE, for the purpose of speeding up paper work in the office I work and I'd like everyone in the office can use it without needing any coding environment. The GUI works fine except that there are some conditional inputs, i.e. if a necessary information can not be read from the pdf during the execution, then it asks the user "x information could not be read, please type it manually or press enter:". Though I can start the running of the program using the GUI, these prompts asking for any input are displayed in spyder console, which is not desired. Is there a way to get those prompts and also answer them using just GUI? Here is my codes for GUI:

```
from tkinter import (Tk, Label, Entry, 
                     Radiobutton, 
                     Button,LEFT,W,StringVar)
                     
import main

# In main.py, pdf_text function pre-evaluates the pdf files and decides what type they are. Based on 
# the type, one of the 5 reading .py files starts the reading and getting the necessary information. 
# These .py files are imported in main.py.

def donus():

    pdf = pdfEntry.get()
    x = var.get()
    if x == "EVET":
        x =  True
    else:x = False
    y = var2.get()
    main.pdf_text(pdf,y,x)

  root = Tk()
root.title('ÇOKLU KALEM PDF DÖNÜŞTÜR')
root.geometry('500x250')

global pdfLabel
pdfLabel=Label(root, text = "PDF DOSYASININ ADINI GİRİNİZ",padx=20)
pdfLabel.pack(anchor=W)

global pdfEntry
pdfEntry = Entry(root, width = 75)
pdfEntry.pack()

var = StringVar(value="1")
global parLabel
parLabel=Label(root, text = "\nTİCARİ TANIMLARDA (VARSA) PARANTEZ İÇİNDEKİ BİLGİLER ALINSIN MI?",
                justify = LEFT,
                padx=20)
               
parLabel.pack(anchor=W)

global evetRadio
evetRadio = Radiobutton(root, 
                        text = "EVET, ALINSIN",
                        padx=20,
                        variable=var, value="EVET")
evetRadio.pack(anchor=W)

global hayırRadio
hayırRadio = Radiobutton(root, 
                         text = "HAYIR, ALINMASIN",
                         variable=var,
                         padx=20,value="HAYIR")
hayırRadio.pack(anchor=W)

var2 = StringVar(value="1")
global proLabel
proLabel=Label(root, text = "\nHANGİ FORMAT İÇİN DÖNÜŞTÜRME YAPILACAK?",padx=20)
proLabel.pack(anchor=W)

global proRadio
proRadio = Radiobutton(root, text = "PROAKTİF", variable=var2, padx=20, value="PROAKTİF")
proRadio.pack(anchor=W)

global ncRadio
ncRadio = Radiobutton(root, text = "NCTS",variable=var2, padx=20, value="NCTS")
ncRadio.pack(anchor=W)

global exeButton
exeButton = Button(root,text = "DÖNÜŞTÜR", command =donus, width = 20, height= 2)
exeButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can use [`simpledialog.askstring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.simpledialog.askstring) instead of console `input()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works. I have also learnt to use messagebox.showinfo() and messagebox.askquestion()